# Out of memory exception when reading and displaying the data from excel in angular 2

Tags: c#, excel, angular, observable, openxml-sdk

I am developing asp.net web api which reads excel data using OpenXML SDK for Excel to read the data and display in angular2. There are about 70,000 rows of data to be displayed and all need to be displayed in one go. Please note that this to plot the data on the screen and hence no paging involved. When I run the application in chrome I get out of memory exception.The data loads quick from the webapi but takes times to render on angular 2 and eventually a out of memory message is thrown. Please note that I am using rxjs observable.  When Can anybody tell me the efficient way to do it which is fast. Do you think my web api should be async and if yes how do i implement it

```
@Injectable()
export class StatsService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private statsUrl = 'http://localhost:45870/api/statstracker';

    getStats(): Observable<Stats[]> {

        return this.http.get(this.statsUrl )
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
    }
}
```

Here is my code

```
public List<StatsModel> OpenSpreadsheetDocument(string filepath)
        {

            List<StatsModel> model = new List<StatsViewModel>();


            // Open a SpreadsheetDocument based on a filepath.
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();


                foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {

                    StatsViewModel statsModel= new StatsViewModel ();
                    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                    {

                        if (c.CellReference.Value.Contains("A"))
                            statsModel.timestamp = c.CellValue.Text;


                        if (c.CellReference.Value.Contains("B"))
                        {
                            decimal d = 0;
                            Decimal.TryParse(c.CellValue.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
                            statsModel.lat = d;
                        }
                        if (c.CellReference.Value.Contains("C"))
                        {
                            decimal d = 0;
                            Decimal.TryParse(c.CellValue.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
                            statsModel.lng = d;
                        }
                    }
                    model.Add(statsModel);

                }
                model.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            return model;

        }
```

**web api method**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer()
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customerViewModel = service.GetSpreadsheet();
            return Ok(customerViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing   model.RemoveAt(0);?

Comment: 70K rows is *not* a lot. Check your code. For example, Lists increase by doubling an internal buffer and may throw if memory becomes so fragmented that the runtime can't find a large enough memory range. Since you already know how many items there are, set the List's capacity with the appropriate overload

Comment: because it reads value 0,1 and 2 which is not in my excel. I think it is column values

Comment: Sorry Panagiotis didnt get you. Any suggestions on how to handle that

Comment: Post the full exception message, including the call stack. You can get this with `Exception.ToString()`. Right now, we can only guess what the issue may be. As for the List constructior - just google it. Or write `new List<..>(70000)`. Also *remove* that `RemoveAt(0)`. If you don't want the first element, don't add it at all. Anyway, post the call stack

Answer (score 0):

While it's odd that your List could cause out-of-memory with 70 000 items you could solve the problem by returning an `IEmumerable<StatsModel>` instead of a `List<StatsModel>`. In effect, you'd be returning a delegate for retrieving the contents instead of the actual data. This would give you more possibilities to run OpenSpreadsheetDocument asynchronously and what not. To give you an idea:

```
public IEnumerable<StatsModel> OpenSpreadsheetDocument(string filepath)
{
     using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
     {
          // Initialize sheetData here
          return sheetData.Elements<Row>().Select 
          (r=> {
              var statsModel= new StatsViewModel ();
              // Copy-paste everything you had in your old "foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())" block here
              return statsModel;
          });
      }
}
```

Comment: gettting compilation error atreturn sheetData.Elements<Row>().Select<StatsViewModel> . Ienumerable has no extension for Select. Also could you give me a relevant code in the  // Do your thing with statsModel here, using row.Elements<Cell>()

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've corrected the code. It should be .Select(...), not .Select<...>(...)

Comment: By "Do your thing", I'm referring to that you can basically copy-paste your entire code block of 
    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
    { 
        // Your code 
    }

Comment: I tried this but there was no diffrence. My chrome browser was becoming unresponsive and got memory exception. I feel its issue with the angular service as when i test the controller it pulls the data fine

Comment: I have updated my post with the web api method and some description to it. Let me know if you have any thoughts on it